# php wont direct me to the 'action' page

Tags: php, html

I have two pages which are (sigin.php , validateIn.php)
the form the is submitted by the user in the 'signin' page, then gets validated in the 'validateIn' page.

The problem is that the server doesn't redirect me to the 'validateIn' page and it just reloads the current page 'signin'.

I have included the action attribute in the form tag.

I have tried using the `header('Location:***.php)` function 
none of these worked for me.

I have included a number of "echo" statements to know the path of the compiler.

> Signin.php

```
           <form action="validateIn.php" method="POST">
    <strong>    <label> Student Number: </strong>
        <input id="studentNumber" type="text" name="studentNumber"
        value="<?php echo isset($_POST['studentNumber']) ? $_POST['studentNumber'] : '' ?>">
    </label> <br>

    <strong>    <label> Password:   </strong>
        <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass">
    </label> <br>

    <input id="signin" type="submit" name="signin" value="Sign In" >
</form>
```

> vaildateIn.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signin'])) { //if 1
    echo "if number 1 <br>";
    if(!empty($_POST['studentNumber']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) ){ //if 2
        echo "if number 2";
        $number = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['studentNumber']);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass']));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_number=$number AND password=$pass";
        $result = mysqli_query($$conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) { //if 3
            echo "if number 3";
            header('Location:home.php');
        } else { //else 1
            echo "else number 1";
            header('Location:signin.php');
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "else number 2";
}
```

Comment: your html is invalid due to the nature of your label / strong tags

Comment: `!empty('name') && !empty('pass')` ~ are these `constants` defined elsewhere or supposed to be `$_POST` variables?

Comment: i removed the <strong> tag from the 'signin' page but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: do not use `md5` for password hashing as it is not secure - use `password_hash` and `password_verify` instead

Comment: Your sql is wide open to sql injection attacks - use `prepared statements` instead of embedding variables in the sql

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr ) : string` - i.e. you haven't set a link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()`. Also, `$result` is undefined.

Comment: The privacy isn't that important for me right now because i am working locally and it is just a school project

Comment: I have defined the $result variable (it was already in the code in the compiler but i must've deleted it by accident)

Comment: I see you have changed the question content so as to negate previous comment about variables/ constants. What DOES your code do? Where does it get to? ie... which echo statement runs??

Comment: it only prints the 'if number 1'

Comment: and it doesn't execute the   "if(!empty($_POST['studentNumber']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) )" ,   I have added an else statement for this one and it prints what is inside of the else statement

Answer (score 0):

To add the hashed version of the user's password to the database, semi-pseudo code might be:

```
    <form method='post'>
        <label>username:<input type='text' name='username' /></label>
        <label>studentNumber:<input type='text' name='studentNumber' /></label>
        <label>password:<input type='password' name='pass' /></label>
        <input type='submit' />
    </form>

    <?php
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

            $args=array(
                'studentNumber'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'username'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'pass'              =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
            );
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );

            $pwdhash=password_hash( $pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

            $sql='insert into `student` set `username`=? `student_number`=?, `password`=?';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $studentNumber, $pwdhash );


            $stmt->execute();
        }
    ?>
```

If you were to assume that passwords had been stored in the database as correctly formed hashes using `password_hash` then the approach you would use to verify the user credentials could be like this:

```
    <form action="validateIn.php" method="POST">
        <label>
            <strong>Student Number: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="studentNumber" value="<?php echo isset( $_POST['studentNumber'] ) ? $_POST['studentNumber'] : '' ?>" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
            <strong>Password:</strong>
            <input type="password" name="pass" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    </form>


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

    $args=array(
        'studentNumber'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'pass'              =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
    );
    $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
    extract( $_POST );

    if( isset( $studentNumber, $pass ) ){
        $sql='select `password` from `student` where `student_number`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $studentNumber );

        $res=$stmt->execute();
        if( $res ){
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result( $pwdhash );
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();

            if( $pwdhash == password_verify( $pass, $pwdhash ) ){
                /* ok - redirect accordingly */
            }else{
                /* bogus - */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With regards to the logic used in your form and validateIn.php script - this appears to work fine for me ( removed all the db calls though ) - hope this all proves of some help but I will say that you are wrong to assume that security is not important in your project as it is just a school exercise.... never too early to adopt best practise '-)

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* POST to same page to emulate posting to validateIn.php */
        if( isset( $_POST['signin'] ) ) {

            echo "if number 1 <br>";



            if( isset( $_POST['studentNumber'], $_POST['pass'] ) && !empty( $_POST['studentNumber'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass'] ) ){

                echo "if number 2";

            } else {

                echo 'Bogus - empty or missing fields';

            }
        } else{ 
            echo "else number 2";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="POST">
            <label>
                <strong>Student Number: </strong>
                <input type="text" name="studentNumber" value="<?php echo isset( $_POST['studentNumber'] ) ? $_POST['studentNumber'] : '' ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                <strong>Password:</strong>
                <input type="password" name="pass" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name='signin' value="Sign In" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't work too, The problem is that the server won't direct me to the 'validateIn' page unless that the two fields 'studentNumber, password' is empty, meaning that if they are not empty the server just reloads the current page 'signin'\

Comment: that cannot be the case. To be redirected back to the `signin` page the sql query must fail and thus the `header('Location:signin.php');` is called